# Angular: ForkJoin ngrx observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an ngrx store that contains multiple states. I'm trying to construct one object (Rent object) by gathering data from each state:
Here is my code:

```
ngOnInit() {


  //Fetch the rent and its properties data
  const rentID = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

  let rentState$ = this.store.select('rentState');
  let clientState$ = this.store.select('clientState');
  let vehiculeState$ = this.store.select('vehiculesState');
  let paymentState$ = of(null);//TODO

  let importRent$ = forkJoin([rentState$, vehiculeState$, clientState$, paymentState$])
    .pipe(mergeMap(([rentData, vehiculeData, clientData, paymentData]: [any, any, any, any]) => {
      let rent = new Rent();

      rent = rentData.rentList.filter(rent => rent.id === rentID)[0];

      rent.vehicule = vehiculeData.vehicules.filter(vehicule => vehicule.id === this.rent.vehicule.id)[0];

      rent.client = clientData.clientList.filter(client => client.id === this.rent.client.id)[0];
      rent.companion = clientData.companionList.filter(companion => companion.id === this.rent.companion.id)[0];

      //TODO: retrieve payments

      return of(rent);
    }))


  importRent$.subscribe(data => console.log('hello'));

}
```

But I don't get any message 'hello' in my console. For some reason the code the subscription does not happen.

I already have these imports in my code:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

The store already has data in it. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you positive that ALL of the states emit and complete? Try with `combineLatest`? And I don't think you need to put the `observables` in an array as a paramter for `forkJoin`

Comment: `forkJoin` requires all source Observables to complete. Maybe in your case it would be sufficient to chain `this.store.select('rentState')` with `pipe(take(1))`

Comment: @ChauTran, You are right, it seems the states did not complete and emit. I used `combineLatest` and it worked. Why don't you submit it as an answer I mark it as one. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you positive that ALL of the states emit and complete? Try with `combineLatest`? And I don't think you need to put the observables in an array as a paramter for `forkJoin`.

While using `combineLatest`, everytime a `child-source` Observable emits after the initial emit of all `child-source`, the whole thing emits. You might wanna look into `distinctUntilChanged` as well if you don't want `over-emitting` scenario.

`1 emits, 2 emits` => `combineLatest emits` => `1 emits` => `combineLatest emits` etc...

Answer (score 4):

As @martin said in his comment

> `forkJoin` requires all source Observables to complete.

So you just need to take the first value emitted with `take(1)` or `first()`:

```js
let importRent$ = combineLatest(
  rentState$.pipe(take(1)), 
  vehiculeState$.pipe(take(1)), 
  clientState$.pipe(take(1)), 
  paymentState$.pipe(take(1))
)
```